# union of two polygon layers is giving an empty line layer

Tags: pyqgis, union, vector-layer

I have created new temporary layers with selected features for the two layers .Then I am trying to do union of the two said temporary layers.

temporary layer1

```
      if ('Districts'==layer.name()):
            val=int(layer.type())
            provider = layer.dataProvider()

            # Get the currently selected layer
            inLayer = layer

            inFields = inLayer.dataProvider().fields()

            inLayerGeometryType = ['Point','Line','Polygon'][inLayer.geometryType()]

            # Convert its CRS to a string we can pass to QgsVectorLayer's constructor
            inLayerCRS = inLayer.crs().authid()

            # Make the output layer

            outLayer = QgsVectorLayer(inLayerGeometryType + '?crs='+inLayerCRS, 'dp_Slope', 'memory')

            # Copy the fields from the old layer into the new layer
            outLayer.startEditing()
            outLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes(inFields.toList())
            outLayer.commitChanges()

            # Add it to the map

##                inFields = layer.dataProvider().fields()
##                writer = QgsVectorFileWriter( "temp_Slope.shp", provider.encoding(), provider.fields(),QGis.WKBPolygon, provider.crs() )
##                newlayer = iface1.addVectorLayer("temp_Slope.shp", "temp_Slope.shp", "ogr")

            if (val==0):
                iface1.setActiveLayer(layer)
                v=[self.listWidget_SlopeDrought.item(i) for i in range(self.listWidget_SlopeDrought.count())]
                flag=0
                selects=[]
                for i in range(self.listWidget_SlopeDrought.count()):
                    v=self.listWidget_SlopeDrought.item(i) 
                    state=v.checkState()
                    if state==2 and self.groupBox_slopeDrought.isChecked():
                        flag=1
                        value=self.listWidget_SlopeDrought.item(i).text()
                        query=" \"{}\" {} '{}' ".format(value1,"=",value)
                        selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
                        layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

                        ourFeat = QgsFeature()
                        for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
                            ourFeat.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
                            ourFeat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
                            j=outLayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([ourFeat])
                            outLayer.updateExtents()
                if flag==1:
                    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
                    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(outLayer, 'dp_Slope.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
                    layer.removeSelection()
                    self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled (1, True)
                    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,"Layer Created!","Temporary layer for Slope created as dp_Slope")
                    self.groupBox_slopeDrought.setEnabled(False)
                    self.pushButton_nextSlopeDrought.setEnabled(False)
                    #self.pushButton_ResetCheckDam_slope.setEnabled(True)
                    flag=0
                    #self.label_alreadyCreated_slope_cd.show()
                    #self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled (0, False)
                elif flag==0 and self.groupBox_slopeDrought.isChecked():
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self,"No value selected!","Please select value(s) to create layer")
                else:
                    self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled (1, True)
                    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

temporary layer2

```
if ('Soil'==layer.name()):
            val=int(layer.type())
            provider = layer.dataProvider()

            # Get the currently selected layer
            inLayer = layer
            # Get its list of fields
            inFields = inLayer.dataProvider().fields()

            # Convert its geometry type enum to a string we can pass to
            # QgsVectorLayer's constructor
            inLayerGeometryType = ['Point','Line','Polygon'][inLayer.geometryType()]

            # Convert its CRS to a string we can pass to QgsVectorLayer's constructor
            inLayerCRS = inLayer.crs().authid()

            # Make the output layer

            outLayer = QgsVectorLayer(inLayerGeometryType + '?crs='+inLayerCRS, 'dp_Soil', 'memory')

            # Copy the fields from the old layer into the new layer
            outLayer.startEditing()
            outLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes(inFields.toList())
            outLayer.commitChanges()

            if (val==0):
                iface1.setActiveLayer(layer)

                value=self.doubleSpinBoxSoilDrought.value()

                query=" \"{}\" {} '{}' ".format(value1,"<",value)

                selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
                layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

                ourFeat = QgsFeature()
                for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
                    ourFeat.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
                    ourFeat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
                    j=outLayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([ourFeat])
                    outLayer.updateExtents()

                if value and self.groupBox_soilDrought.isChecked():
                    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
                    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(outLayer, 'dp_Soil.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
                    layer.removeSelection()
                    self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled (2, True)
                    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,"Layer Created!","Temporary layer for soil created as dp_Soil")

                    self.groupBox_soilDrought.setEnabled(False)
                    self.pushButton_nextSoilDrought.setEnabled(False)
                    self.operations()

                elif not value and self.groupBox_soilDrought.isChecked():
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self,"No value selected!","Please select value(s) to create layer")
                elif not self.groupBox_soilDrought.isChecked():
                    self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled (2, True)
                    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
```

Then I m doing union

```
operation='qgis:union'
val1='dp_Slope'
val3='dp_Soil'
val4='result_dp'
processing.runalg(operation,val1,val3, val4+".shp")
layerAdded = iface1.addVectorLayer(os.getcwd(),'result_dp', "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layerAdded )
```

Comment: Are you trying to load the two temporary layer in qgis? Are they correct? Do you reach to do the Union by the gui?

Comment: ya I m trying through gui..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found a easier way to create layer from selected features of layer..

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer, "dp_Slope.shp", "utf-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", 1) #1 is for creating layer using selected features
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(os.getcwd()+"/dp_Slope.shp", "dp_Slope", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) #loading layer
```

but anyway the problem was with 
loading the layer separately after doing union

solved it by using

```
processing.runandload(operation,val1,val3, val4+".shp")
```